# html5 video fallback advice (no flash)

Tags: css, video, mobile, html5-video, modernizr

I'm looking for a creative way to replace an HTML5 video with an image under a few circumstances. Don't want to deal with flash or anything like that to make the video work... would rather give them an image.

Give them the image if:

1. If the desktop browser doesn't support HTML5 video
2. If the user is mobile

Seems simple... especially by using Modernizr for css tags with `display:none;` if the video isn't supported ... so here's the caveat: The HTML5 video is edge to edge and centered to the screen with JavaScript and I'd like the image to have the same behavior.

My initial thought was simple: poster attribute. Works on an iPad and iPhone 3/3gs, but is playable on an iPhone 4.. Also, doesn't work on IE, which apparently says "I don't know what this is" and doesn't even bother with the poster.

I've got a test set up at http://kzmnt.com/test/

Looking forward to your advice!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want your video to play on mobile? And what would you consider mobile (tablets, smart phones, older crap phones, netbooks, PSP)?

Comment: The video's pretty large and in charge.. and takes the entire background. Aside from iOS behavioral differences on iPad vs iPhone 4 vs iPhone 3G/3Gs, I think it's kind of rude to hit someone with a data plan with a video they didn't have the option of watching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a media query after about 1100px and replaced it with an image using css background size set to cover!

Answer (score 2):

You can check if HTML5 video is supported with the following:

```
function supports_h264_baseline_video() {
 if (!supports_video()) { return false; }
 var v = document.createElement("video");
 return v.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
}
```

As far as mobile goes, try using some media queries.

The above code is from http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#video-formats.