# Detect if the UIWebView can play video inline on iPhone ( allowsInlineMediaPlayback )

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview, html5-video

I am trying to tell if my video is going to play inline once the user starts the video (as apposed to fullscreen/in the native video player) on an iPhone in a UIWebView **before** the video has started. I have no way of knowing if the UIWebView has the setting `allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES` as i do not know in what app or on what page my video is being displayed.

My goal is to only show the video if it can be played inline.

Is there any way to read the allowsInlineMediaPlayback setting from javascript, or detect if my video will play inline or not?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451687/detect-if-client-allows-inline-media-playback-for-html5-video

Comment: Asked here as well with no answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129906/detect-if-browser-device-can-play-html5-video-inline-before-playing

Answer (score 2):

Everything I have read on the apple developers website seems to suggest that it will automatically play in full screen mode in safari. Now if they are using another app, as far as I know you do not have access to that apps UIWebViews properties. However, in an attempt to not be totally useless, here is a link to all of the methods you can query and you might find some useful information in there.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/HTMLMediaElementClassReference/HTMLMediaElement/HTMLMediaElement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009355-CH18-SW27

Some more information that may be useful to you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW1