# Fallback for video background in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am trying to add a static image as fallback for video background in html 5 but not getting the output can anyone help.

```html
<div class="background-wrap">
     <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted>
         <source src="media/Digital Marketing Agency in CT - Mediaboom.ogv">
        <img src="/media/staticimage.jpg" title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag">
         
            Video not supported
        </video>
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616453/image-placeholder-fallback-for-html5-video

Comment: Dude i had tried with that solution it was not working .Thats why posted here again.And the solution given here by someone worked.You should not have deleted the answer.Anyhow I got the answer .Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check for you image path and replace the `<video>` tag in the title with `&lt; &gt;`

```
<div class="background-wrap">
    <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="media/Digital Marketing Agency in CT - Mediaboom.ogv">
    <img src="/media/staticimage.jpg" 
      title="Your browser does not support the &lt;video&gt; tag">

        Video not supported
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of using an image inside the video area, you use a background image.

```
#video-bg-elem {background-image: url(media/staticimage.jpg);}

<div class="background-wrap">
 <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="media/Digital Marketing Agency in CT - Mediaboom.ogv">
  Video not supported
 </video>
</div>
```