# set fallback for <video> HTML tag if the video link is not working

Tags: html

I wanna set a fallback image or message if the video link is deleted or not working.

I'm not looking for a fallback image if the browser does not support  tags,

is there an easy way to do so? I'm working on a page with so many videos,
thought I'd send an HTTP request using JS for each video but I might end up sending so many.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image placeholder fallback for HTML5 Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616453/image-placeholder-fallback-for-html5-video)

Answer (score 0):

This method does work if you provide an invalid link but will will display the error message if the browser does not support the video

```
  <video controls>
  <source src="myVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <p>
     Your browser doesn't support HTML video. Here is
     a <a href="myVideo.mp4">link to the video</a> instead.
  </p>
  </video>
```

reference from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Update: solution using javascript FETCH API

```
 <body>
  <video controls>
    <source class="link" src="<video link>" type="video/webm">
    <p>
      Your browser doesn't support HTML video
    </p>
  </video>

  <p class="videoalt" style="display: none;">
      Error: video link not found 
  </p>

  <script>

    const link = document.querySelector('.link')
    const video = document.querySelector('video')
    const videoalt = document.querySelector('.videoalt')
    const linkSrc = link.src;

    fetch(linkSrc).then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        video.style.display = 'none'
        videoalt.style.display = 'block'
      }
    })

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: to cite the mdn page: _"The content inside the opening and closing <video></video> tags is shown as a fallback in browsers that don't support the element."_ ... but it doesn't solve the condition _"if the video link is deleted or not working"_ and that's the question asked so this doesn't fulfill the request

Comment: As far I know there is not any method to check if the link exists with just HTML, However you can check if the link exists or is deleted using javascript fetch API, a similar solution like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/72799052/17948008

Comment: Feel free to enrich your answer to better fulfill the request with the strategy you suggested with your latest comment. I was just pointing out that an answer should fulfill a question and this answer didn't yet